# How to refer results from my project thesis for my master thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, software-papers

I am continuing the topic from my project thesis as my master thesis with more additional work.

I have to refer/cite to some of my own results from the Project thesis in my master thesis document. Is there any standard way to follow? Or is it no different from referring to other research papers and so on?

Google did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cite as usual (see below). If the project thesis is unpublished then mark it as such. If it is available through some means, such as the university library, it would be helpful to note that, such as in a footnote.

Note that in general your own unpublished work can simply be incorporated into later work for publication. But this seems to be an intermediate case in which the work is "sort of published" as it was submitted for some course work.

But I suggest doing citations and references because it is good practice and avoids all questions of possible self plagiarism. It may be erring on the conservative side, but that is, at least, academically "safe".

Answer (score 1):

Not only you can refer/cite to your project thesis results (if published), you can also reproduce some parts of that (if not published) in your master thesis. That is your work and you have the copyright.